# VLookUp with Nested SUMIFS

Tags: excel, vlookup, sumifs

I have been trying to make a form for some of my team members who are not that computer literate, and I essentially want to make it click and go. I thought I could do it...but alas I am not as good with nesting functions as I thought I was.

I have this spreadsheet where I want to put data into the yellow cell. On the next sheet I have the below table. What I want to do is use a formula to fill H4 with the "Request Branch's" Account Number. Now, I have currently filled the cells with information. They, in fact, have drop down options - which are pulled from the Account List table. As a result the value in H4 will continually change based on the needs of the user - but must be within the confines of the Account List Table.

[image]

[image]

What I have tried is [here](https://www.excel-university.com/multi-column-lookup-with-vlookup-and-sumifs/) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280438/sumifs-with-vlookup). I keep getting result of #Value, or N/A. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I know that I need to nest the SUMIFS withing VLookUp, but I am not sure as to why it won't work.

Comment: What answer do you inspect to get based off what inputs? Share the equation you have tried that led to the errors as well. If you just want the account number I don't see why you need a sum

Comment: I want the yellow cell to be filled with the Requesting Branch's Account Number based on the Carrier name.

Comment: So you expect 10? (This is what I meant so nobody here has to assume. Life is easier when you just state exactly what you expect)

Comment: Yes, in this case as it sits. But it will not always be that way. Let me edit my question to be more clear. I apologize.

Comment: Also that SUMIF won't work for your last value since they are all strings.

Comment: @urdearboy that explains the erros. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm providing you with two *possible* solutions.

**1)** The first one uses the SUMPRODUCT function. You may not have seen this kind of notation before.

When ranges are multiplied by each other like so `(B3:B8=G3)*(C3:C8=G4)` they are actually turned into boolean arguments. If you highlighted this part of the code and pressed F9 it would look like this: `{0;0;0;0;1;0;0}`. This is an array where TRUE for both criteria meet. So our Branch is "A" and our Carrier is "F". In the rest of the cases either or both are false resulting in zeroes.

Now if you multiply this array by the range with account numbers, obviously the only number remaining will be the one multiplied by 1 and so you have the answer **however keep in mind that as you are multiplying if the account is not a number the function will fail!**

**2)** This is why we have a second method using `=INDEX()` and `=MATCH()` functions.

To overly simplify this - the `INDEX` function grabs contents from an array at a specified position (row and column), while the `MATCH` function gets the position of an item in an array.

The idea with using ranges as multiple criteria is the same as in the first example, **however this time** when we get our array of zeroes and ones `{0;0;0;0;1;0;0}` we use the match function to find at which position our criteria cross (as seen on the screenshot it's the 5th position, as it's in the 5th row of the entire column D, the match function searches the `{0;0;0;0;1;0;0}` array for a `1` and returns its position in the array) and so this is our ROW.

Knowing the position of the contents we searched for we use the `INDEX` function to grab the contents of the cell in that position so `=INDEX(D2:D8,MATCH(1, INDEX((B2:B8=G3)*(C2:C8=G4),0),0))` is actually `=INDEX(D2:D8, 5)` meaning that the `INDEX` function grabs contents of the 5th row from the range `D2:D8` which is cell `D6`.

[image]
*The green boxes are just there to show the instance where both of our criteria are met (cross).*

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Account],SUMPRODUCT((Table1[Branch]=F$3)*(Table1[Carrier]=F$4)*ROW(Table1[Account]))-1)
```

Note that you may have to adjust the final `-1`. This is because the indexed table starts in row #2 and the SUMPRODUCT function returns a sheet row number. If your table would start in a different row the difference between the sheet row and table row would be larger. It must be adjusted here. Or you might work with sheet references (named ranges) and require no adjustment at all.